# C# OpenFileDialog doesn't display content, it displays file directory

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

So for my first program in c# I want to make a bot. 
I already got some of the GUI made, but everything is not positioned as how I want it.

Whenever I try to load a text file with no specific content in the file using OpenFileDialog, it instead displays the directory in the Rich Text Box and not the actual content of the file.

GUI: http://puu.sh/5kLK6.png

When loading a file I get this instead of the actual content: http://puu.sh/5kLL2.png

The actual content of the file is "wepufhwoighwiar"
Code of Load Proxies Button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";

            openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                proxieslist.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OpenFileDialog` does not open the file for you. It just helps you select some file to open. To open a file, you have to use some classes in the namespace `System.IO`. Here is a simple code to read all the text (plaintext):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   proxieslist.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much King King, will choose you as best answer in 7 minutes when STF allows me to.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a helpful hint, It is good practice to initialize your objects like this, It cuts down some code,looks prettier and cuts down on repetitive typing too.. :)

```
var openFileDialog1 = 
        new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"C:\" ,
            Title = "Browse Text Files" ,
            CheckFileExists = true ,
            CheckPathExists = true ,
            DefaultExt = "txt" ,
            Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ,
            FilterIndex = 2 ,
            RestoreDirectory = true ,
            ReadOnlyChecked = true ,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you could use `StreamReader`:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\cake.txt", Encoding.UTF8);  //declare;
string cakeCode = sr.ReadToEnd();   //read cake.txt through to cakeCode (a string containing the text of cake's)
sr.Close();   //The End.
```